# Extract only file names from an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3

I have a requirement to extract only file names from an Amazon S3 bucket without those extra 3 zeros after `.csv`, I'm doing that like this

```
# remove files so every time you have new names
rm ListOfFiles.txt

# get file names
aws s3 ls <bucket-address-directory-path> | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/.csv000*/.csv/g' >> ListOfFiles.txt
```

I'm getting all those file names but there is a blank line at the top as directory there is a Folder. I don't need that folder, neither the blank line.

**What in S3**

```
Archive
ABC.csv000
BCD.csv000
DEF.csv000
```

**What I'm getting**

```
<a blank line here>
ABC.csv
BCD.csv
DEF.csv
```

**What I need**

```
ABC.csv
BCD.csv
DEF.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine `awk` and `sed` into one command, something like

```
aws s3 ls <bucket-address-directory-path> | sed -nr 's/.* ([^ ]*.csv)000.*/\1/p'
```

or

```
aws s3 ls <bucket-address-directory-path> | awk 'NF>3 { sub(/000$/,"", $4); print $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

change "{print $4}" to "{if(NR>1){print $4}}"